# LoadError: cannot load such file -- spree/core/preference_rescue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, database-migration, spree

I am trying to setup an old app. It is using Rails 3.2.9 and Spree 2.0 stable, my local Ruby version is 2.1.5.

When I run `rake db:migrate`, I am getting an error lot of errors like:

`LoadError: cannot load such file -- spree/core/preference_rescue`

`Polyglot::PolyglotLoadError: Failed to load /path/name/app/db/migrate/20120320231604_new_preferences.spree.rb using extensions deface, rb1`

Comment: I'm pretty sure Rails 3.2.x is not compatible with Ruby 2.2. Try to use an older ruby version

Comment: @Aguardientico almost! I used Ruby 1.9.3, the other migration errors disappeared, but I still got `==  AddMatchRulesToShippingMethods: migrated (0.0915s) ========================

rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- spree/core/preference_rescue`

Comment: try running `bundle install`, yes I know probably you did it. Also, try running `spree install`

Comment: thanks for all your help. I just ran `rake db:schema:load` as workaround